# $.each on an object, returning empty child object

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I'm somewhat a JS newbie and I'm having an issue..

I have an object with child objects :

[image]

And I'm doing a `jQuery.each` on it to deal with each object individually :

```
findResultPersonality: function(r){
    $.each(r, function(index, value){
        if(typeof(value.data) !== 'undefined'){
            console.log(value);
            console.log(value.data);
        }
    })
}
```

With my console.log I'm getting each object individually, with data object filled in, but when I'm trying to access directly the data object, I'm getting an empty object...

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What happens if you try a javascript for loop and index using `console.log(value[i])`?

Comment: How are you calling findResultPersonality? Like this: `findResultPersonality(object.data)`? Be sure that an array is being passed into findResultPersonality.

Comment: Ohhh, try `value['data']` instead of `value.data`

Comment: I am passing the whole object showed in first image in `findResultPersonality(object)` , `value['data']` doesn't change anything, still getting empty object ..

Comment: Try my first comment.

Comment: Why not log `value.data[0]` and see what it says? Or try `console.dir()` instead of `console.log()`.

Comment: @Nicolas > I tried it, but I get "undefined", because value is one of the numbered object (1, 2, 3 ...), so shouldn't I be able to access data object in it directly ?

Comment: Tried it here, and it works as expected. Can you create a jsfiddle reproducing the problem? Two questions: which browser, and is the object really just a plain object, or is there anything special applied to it?

Comment: Oh right. Use the name of the array in place of `value` in the javascript loop.

Comment: Tested with Firefox and Chrome, same issue. I have tried `console.log($.isEmptyObject(value.data))` and it's returning true on both browsers. Well, i'm modifying an existing WordPress plugin, so providing a jsfiddle will be kinda complicated...

Comment: @Nicolas > Well i just tried it with the real name of the array in the loop : `console.log(results[index].data);` , still getting an empty object ...

Comment: @jcaron => No it's really a plain object, getting his properties from functions (made my the plugin author) like this `results[data.id].data = result.s;`  `var result = checker(name, data, $this, $questionList);`

Comment: @Kaz, can you try using a different name for `data`? The only thing I can imagine is that something somewhere is "overloading" things and not giving you access to the `data` property but to something else.